# How to get this in decimal value instead of null in this case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

I am trying to get value in Decimal in this query but unable to get I am getting NULL Value

```
 SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST(SUM(CAST(0 AS INT)) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) * 100 /
 CAST(NULLIF(SUM(CAST(0 AS INT)) + 
 SUM(CAST(0 AS INT)) + SUM(CAST(0 AS INT)), 0) 
 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS DECIMAL)AS VARCHAR)AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

I have tried with Select ISNULL() and it is getting output `0.00`

Is there any other way to get `0.00`
rather than `ISNULL`

Comment: What's your objection to using `ISNULL`? That may affect what other answers can be suggested.

Comment: And if you had an objection to using `ISNULL`, why did you accept [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18359348/61305) on your previous question? Delete this question, go back to that question, and explain why `ISNULL` is not acceptable.

Comment: If you want ANSI standard SQL, you can use `COALESCE` instead. But it may be slower than `ISNULL`

Comment: @podiluska the only case where there will be any difference whatsoever is if the expression is a subquery (in which case `COALESCE` may evaluate it twice). In this case they are 100% interchangeable with no measurable performance difference whatsoever.

Comment: yeah this query has been used in procedure where it is first count and for the second count same ISNULL query is working fine but for this one is giving error..

Comment: The data type of substitution parameter 3 does not match the expected type of the format specification

Comment: What error? If you're getting an error message from the accepted answer on the other question, I doubt the source is `ISNULL`. Post details back to that question instead of just creating a new question with a requirement that you're not sure will actually solve the problem.